# How to modify the default feed via a function

Tags: php, functions, feed

I am trying to add a functionality to the default wordpress feed. The problem is i managed to do this modifying the rss feed php file. The problem number two that i have in mind is when wp gets an update also that file will be updated and my code will disappear.

So i am looking to for a way to insert my code as a filter or something else for the rss feed.

Note: **My code does not modify the default feed content, instead i want to display another feed from external site.**

```
add_filter( 'the_name_for_the_rss_filter', 'my_function' );

function my_function( $some_var ){ global $some_var;

if($some_var == true){

// let's say: 
// echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/feed/");
// exit(0);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out the `template_redirect` action to overwrite the default feed template:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_template_redirect' );
function custom_template_redirect() {
    if (!is_feed()) 
         return;

    header('Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type('rss-http') . '; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset'), true);

    // your own template stuff here 

    exit();     
}
```

Comment: this works only for post feed not for `example.com/feed/` main feed :(

Comment: ok it seems to work on my install, sometimes the feed is cached in the browser, try it with a cache-busting parameter like example.com/feed/?t=1

Comment: that worked. It seems that your code is what i was looking for. Thank you for your time!

Comment: ok great, I added a `header()` example from the default rss2 template that you can modify to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use [fetch_feed()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) if you want to parse an external feed:

```
<?php $feed = fetch_feed( $uri ); ?>
```

UPDATE 1: Remove the default feeds:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );
```

UPDATE 2: Add a custom feed:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_custom_feed');
function add_custom_feed() {
    echo '<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Custom Feed" href="' . get_bloginfo('rss_url') . '" />'; 
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you, i will use `fetch_feed` but actually i don't know how to not display the default feed and display my 'fetched feed' one.

Comment: @m3tsys Try adding the code from my two updates to your `functions.php`